# How to distinguish fundamental mass from energy mass?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, mass-energy, higgs

I have just read Einstein's famous formula, Energy-mass Equation, that is
$$E=mc^2$$
Or As Einstein wrote it
$$m=\frac{E}{c^2}$$

Now I have learned that any energy of the particle like potential or kinetic energy, actually causes an increase in the mass of the particle. For instance, Suppose I have a moving clock and a rest clock then the moving clock has greater mass than the rest one because It has extra kinetic and thermal, and potential energy which makes it heavier than the rest one.

Further, I know that when you get closer and closer to particles like saying proton, they have quarks potential energy that too results as mass. So at a basic fundamental level, it seems to have the only energy. But this is not true, particle has mass due to the Higgs field which depends on the way these particles interact with the Higgs field. So we can categories these masses into two categories, one which comes from the Higgs field (that I call fundamental) and the other which comes from this energy thing (I Call it energy mass).

Now First things Is there a way to distinguish these masses. I mean a way that tells me that this part of the mass is fundamental and this from energy mass?

Second things, Because we have this relationship that connects energy to mass or vice versa, Can we just swept out the concept of the Higgs field giving mass and make our self with only energy? I mean it's good to have only one fundamental concept.

Comment: Not an answer, just a minor correction. The Higgs mechanism gives mass to quarks and electrons, but most of the proton's mass comes from binding energy. The proton's mass would be almost unchanged even if quarks were massless. You can read about this in Wilczek's Nobel Lecture (https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2018/06/wilczek-lecture.pdf). From page 111: "the mass of ordinary matter derives almost entirely from energy -– the energy of massless gluons and nearly massless quarks, which are the ingredients from which protons, neutrons, and atomic nuclei are made."

Comment: Gratitude for this minor correction.