Can electrons or protons due to fusion reduce in their individual mass?
It's a ridiculous question, but that's why I am asking it after getting confused over a paragraph about nuclear fusion in my textbook.

The total mass of a stable nucleus is slightly less than the combined
mass of the individual protons and neurons ... the mass defect in
nuclei can be converted into energy using $E = mc^2$.This is known as
the binding energy of the nucleus... each nucleus has its own binding energy value, with a higher value indicating a more stable nucleus."

Reading this paragraph is what got me to the following, ridiculous conclusion. The conclusion is that the product of fusion has electrons and protons with less mass than its inputs. This seemed to suggest to me - unintuitively, that electrons and protons somehow lose their mass. But that just seems off.
What I do know is what happened to that so-called "missing" mass or as the book calls it, "mass defect." The mass has become what's called the "binding energy" of our new, combined molecule. This binding energy outlines exactly what we need to use to break it apart again (and return to its previous state).
I might be finding thsi blurry due to my assumption that all the mass we consider before fusion comes from the purely the total mass of the electrons and the protons (that make up the atoms pre-fusion). But that is as much as I can muster, and I will leave it you, my global experts, to untangle my confusion.
I might need to rewrite this, since my brain has been at it for the whole day.
Regards,
HBP

Your assumption is exactly what leads you to this incorrect conclusion.
Einstein's $E=mc^2$ states that systems of particles gain/lose mass by means of gaining/losing energy. Meaning that the mass of a system is not only the sum of the mass of the composite particles but you also need to take into account the energy due to their interactions.
Most of the time we don't notice this effect, because it's negligible: strong chemical reactions release energy in the order of $eV$, which lowers the systems mass in about $10^{-6}$ to $ 10^{-5}$  the mass of an electron, which is on its own has only $10^{-5}$ to $10^{-4}$ of the mass of a simple chemical compound, meaning the change in mass in a chemical reaction is most of the time smaller than $10^{-10}$ the mass of the system - totally negligible.
However, in the nucleus, the binding energy per nucleus is in the order of $10^{-3}$ of the nucleus's rest mass, meaning that it's quite measurable and you can't neglect it any more.
In conclusion, the mass of the system is not only made of the masses of the individual particles, but also their energy. Meaning that a system can lose mass without the particles themselves changing their rest-mass.
For more information I suggest you watch this excellent youtube video from PBS space-time:
The Real Meaning of E=mc².
Hope this helped!

The video has a link to an English translation of Einstein's original paper. The link is a google redirect. For me, the link didn't work. This did. https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol2-trans/188

@Ofek Gillon Thank you so much! I am sorry for responding to your effort so late. Thanks for making the distinction between when the "missing" mass is significant and when it isn't (it is always there!).  Of course, it is not a missing mass, since - as I am learning - the total mass of a system includes both energy and mass. Edit: Thanks for speaking to my assumption! The blurr is less blurr ... much less now.

From https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/590575/186017:
Mass is the energy in the rest frame of a system divided by c$^2$. In order to be useful as a concept, mass should be constant at the time and energy scale of your experiment. For example, a football has mass. If you kick it it heat up a little, but this change in mass can be neglected when you play.
When you look inside a massive object you will find that not only the mass of the constituent parts contributes but also the binding energy of these. For example the mass of a hydrogen atom consists is m$_p$ +m$_e$ - E$_b$, where E$_b$, positive by definition, contains electro-nuclear potential energy, electron kinetic energy and a proton kinetic energy.

Dear my2cts : Thank you for bringing to attention the concept of rest mass, which @Ofek Gillon also did! It's been a while since I touched relativity ... so perhaps its time to go back and brush up on it!
